# Why won't postgres use my index?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a table `comments` with many fields and one of them is `rating integer not null` and I have added index:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| schemaname   | tablename       | indexname                                           |   tablespace | indexdef
|--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| public       | comments        | comments__rating__idx                               |       <null> | CREATE INDEX comments__rating__idx ON public.comments USING btree (rating)
```

But postgres doesn't want to use it:

```
explain SELECT * from comments where rating > 99999;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Gather  (cost=1000.00..10742798.88 rows=783 width=479)                                  |
|   Workers Planned: 2                                                                    |
|   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on comments  (cost=0.00..10741720.58 rows=326 width=479) |
|         Filter: (rating > 99999)                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN
```

```
explain analyze SELECT * from comments where rating > 1000 limit 1;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                         |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Limit  (cost=0.00..252.79 rows=1 width=479) (actual time=20186.571..20186.573 rows=1 loops=1)                                      |
|   ->  Seq Scan on comments  (cost=0.00..11426310.20 rows=45200 width=479) (actual time=20186.568..20186.568 rows=1 loops=1) |
|         Filter: (rating > 1000)                                                                                                    |
|         Rows Removed by Filter: 161924                                                                                             |
| Planning time: 12.348 ms                                                                                                           |
| Execution time: 20186.908 ms                                                                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN
Time: 20.212s (20 seconds)
```

`set enable_seqscan=false` does not help.

The table is huge(approx 70 mil rows) so there is no sense to not use an index.

Comment: The output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`  would have been more interesting, but anyway: it seems the statistics are way off. The optimizer expects that condition to return 45200 rows (out of 161925). Does running `analyze comments;`change the plan? Why did you apply a `limit` with the second query, but not the first one? And why did you change the condition from `> 99999` to `> 1000`. All those things will drastically change the plan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I remember correctly, that's an artefact, because the estimated value does not take the `LIMIT` into account.

Comment: I tried `analyze comments;`, it didn't help. And I added `limit` cuz I don't want to wait infinite time until rows are fetched (whole table consists of 70 mil rows).

Comment: Is the index valid?  pg_catalog.pg_indexes does not distinguish that.  It will be displayed as extended information on the table (in psql) using `\d+ public.comments`

Comment: @jjanes, yes, it's invalid, thanks a lot. So do I need to run reindex to fix that?

Comment: You can either reindex, or just drop it and recreate it.  Note that reindex will not support "CONCURRENTLY" until v12.

Comment: After reindexing it works, thanks again.